# We have to show that $f_n(x)=x^ne^{-nx}$.

Tags: real-analysis

So, we have to show that $f_n(x)=x^ne^{-nx}$ converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$ ?

Consider pointwise, in case $x\in[0,\infty),f_n\to0,(x^n<e^{nx})$.

Let $\epsilon>0,$ choose $N=\frac{ln(\epsilon)}{lnx -x},$ if $n\le N$ then $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|\frac{x^n}{e^{nx}}-0|<\epsilon$.

My problem, when i choose $N=\frac{ln(\epsilon)}{lnx -x}$ if $x=0,N$ dose not exists  ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f_n'(x)=nx^{n-1}e^{-nx}-nx^ne^{-nx}=nx^{n-1}(1-x)e^{-nx}$. So, $f_n(x)$ is increasing in $[0,1)$ and decreasing in $(1,\infty)$. Therefore, $\max f_n=f_n(1)=e^{-n}$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}=0$, $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to the null function.

Comment: Can i ask some question this $f_n(x)=x^n$ is converges uniformly on $(-1,1)$?, i think it true, check $f_n\to 0 $ on $(-1,1)$ @José Carlos Santos.

Comment: That's another question. I suggest that you post it as such.